Date, Decimal not JSON serializable when encoding a Pydantic model to send in a POST via requests
I am writing a script to post data from an internal system to a third party web API. Our internal system uses data Models defined in Pydantic. I am trying to send data in one of these models to the API using requests.post but it can't serialize some types and it's driving me insane.
Take this data model as an example:
class Product(BaseModel):
    id: int
    group_id: int
    sku: str
    price: Decimal
    special_offer_price: Decimal
    last_update: datetime.date

If I try to send data using this Model using requests.post thus:
product_item = website_api.Product(**product.__dict__)

requests.post(url, headers=jwt_auth.auth_header, json=product_item)

The str and int fields are fine but Decimal and datetime.date fields throw up an exception as they are not serializable, giving the error somewhat like:
TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable

I have tried adding a @field_serializer for the fields to the class definition for pydantic;
    @field_serializer("price", "special_offer_price")
    def serialize_decimal(self, value):
        return str(value)
    
    @field_serializer("last_update")
    def serialize_date(self, value):
        return str(value)

but requests doesn't seem to use it when serializing.

Here:
product_item = website_api.Product(**product.__dict__)

if your product_item is an instance of Product model you mentioned, then you should do:
requests.post(url, headers=jwt_auth.auth_header, json=product_item.model_dump())

You shouldn't need a serializers for datetime.date and Decimal. When I tested this on this Product class I was able to serialize it with product_item.model_dump() without any problem.
Like here:
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Product(BaseModel):
    id: int
    group_id: int
    sku: str
    price: Decimal
    special_offer_price: Decimal
    last_update: datetime.date


product = Product(
    id=1,
    group_id=1,
    sku="123456",
    price=Decimal("100.00"),
    special_offer_price=Decimal("90.00"),
    last_update=datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
)

print(product.model_dump())

produces:
{'id': 1, 'group_id': 1, 'sku': '123456', 'price': Decimal('100.00'), 'special_offer_price': Decimal('90.00'), 'last_update': datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)}

or if you's like it as json string, then this:
print(product.model_dump_json())

produces:
{"id":1,"group_id":1,"sku":"123456","price":"100.00","special_offer_price":"90.00","last_update":"2021-01-01"}


Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. You rock.

For the audience: A @field_serializer specification in Pydantic is triggered when you use Object.model_dump() or Object.model_dump_json() which meant my serializer filters now process the specified fields as intended and the data can be successfully serialized by requests.post into the JSON to send. the model_dump() part was the bit I was missing that converted the object to a Dict that had no un-serializable fields.

The Date object, as the error suggests, is not seriazible by default. For this purpose, you can create an encoder:
import json
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return super().default(obj)

class Product(BaseModel):
    id: int
    group_id: int
    sku: str
    price: Decimal
    special_offer_price: Decimal
    last_update: date

product_item = Product(
    id=1,
    group_id=10,
    sku="ABC123",
    price=Decimal('19.99'),
    special_offer_price=Decimal('15.99'),
    last_update=date.today()
)

product_dict = product_item.dict()
data = json.dumps(product_dict, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    **jwt_auth.auth_header
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

From here and on, you will be able to do whatever you want with this JSON serialized data.

Hi, Ditmar. I was aware of this but unfortunately the inbuilt json= parameter of requests.post doesn't allow me to use a custom encoder when I am running the process.
I did manage to get json.dumps to serialize the object to a text JSON string but passing it as data= to requests.post lead to it being escaped and thus it mangled the JSON.

@MarkBenson I have updated my answer to include a complete example of how one would use it. Would you try it and make sure if it works or not? The json parameter should not be making any issues with custom encoding rules. Make sure to include rules for all the types that occur (see, I have added a Decimal rule, you can similarly add for Integer and Boolean values.) I hope this helps, let me know how it goes.

@MarkBenson Please find a complete working example with a Flask server: https://replit.com/join/wdqfgnjfmy-dimitarvel

@Dimitar I don't think that's the way it should be done. Mark is using Pydantic, and you don't really this amount of custom code when Pydantic already has built in pretty good serialization. Additionally using product_item.dict() is deprecated and instead model_dump() or model_dump_json() should be used. And those methods already produce serialized data ready to be sent with requests.
